# Check if a div contains an image (HTML5 Drag and Drop)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've created a simple drag and drop game with HTML5.
The items drag and drop as they should, however on drop I would like it to check if the image that is placed within the answer box div matches a javascript requirement.

Javascript to handle Drag and Drop events:

```
function allowDrop(ev){
   ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev){
   ev.dataTransfer.setData("content", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev){
   ev.preventDefault();
   var image = ev.dataTransfer.getData("content");
   ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(image));
if($('#answer1').find('#target1').length == 1)
{
    alert("CORRECT!");
}
}
```

might carry out this operation on drop, however nothing happens.
The image is within a div to start with, and the ID of the image itself is `answer1` and the correct answer box is of course `target1`.

Below is the HTML for the drag and drop:

```
<div id="answerBoxes">
<div id="target1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
</div>
<div id="target2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
</div>
<div id="target3" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
</div>
<div id="target4" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
</div>
</div> <!-- end of answerBoxes -->
<div id="whatsWhatContent">
<div id="answers">
   <div id="answer1Box" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
       <img id="answer1" src="Images/Icons/FlowerAnswer.png" draggable="true"    ondragstart="drag(event)" alt="Flower answer box draggable"/>
   </div>


   <div id="answer2Box" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
       <img id="answer2" src="Images/Icons/StemAnswer.png"  draggable="true" 
ondragstart="drag(event)" alt="Stem answer box draggable">
</div>

   <div id="answer3Box" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
      <img id="answer3" src="Images/Icons/RootAnswer.png"  draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" alt="Root answer box draggable">
</div>

   <div id="answer4Box" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
      <img id="answer4" src="Images/Icons/LeafAnswer.png"  draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" alt="Leaf answer box draggable">
</div>
```

CSS For the div around the image:

```
#answer1Box
{
float:left;
width: 125px;
height: 40px;
}
```

CSS for the answer box where the image should be dropped:

```
#target1
{
width: 120px;
height: 38px;
background-color: white;
margin-top: 30px;
border-radius: 5px;
border: 2px solid black;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fSUNX/ for full CSS

Comment: Also nested id's don't make much sense semantically nor does selecting an id like that since id's are unique on the page.

Comment: all image ID's are unique, they're "answer2,3,4" and the answer boxes are "target2,3,4"

Comment: It seems like you are dealing with ``div > img#answer`` but it would be helpful if you could show the markup you are working with.

Comment: I would just use common classes, ids are often overused and they are always trouble due to the higher precedence.

Comment: Have added the markup that deals with the drag and drop and I have also included the full JS that causes the events to occur

Comment: @MattMeadows I've posted a new answer which includes a complete page assembled from your snippets. It works here. I suspect that your jQuery wasn't loading for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a complete version of the game built from the snippets in the question. It seems to perform the Drag-and-drop required, and also identifies the correct answer and `alerts` when the correct image is dragged into the correct box. I've run this in FF21 and Chrome 29

**Note** When I first set this up the jQuery library wasn't loading due to a typo in my `<script>` tag. I'm loading locally, and I'd omitted the `http:` prefix. This gave a behaviour much as described: the image was moved in the DOM to the correct target box, but no alert was generated. Once I corrected this the page worked as intended. I suspect that jQuery wasn't loading in the OP's local version and that this is at the heart of the his problems

I've linked Modernizr in here because the OP indicated that he'd done so. It's not actually doing anything. This code works with or without it.

I had to change the image files because I didn't have the originals.

I have made no other significant changes to the code, CSS or HTML.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>DND with alerts</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<style>
#answer1Box,#answer2Box,#answer3Box,#answer4Box
{
float:left;
width: 125px;
height: 40px;
}

#target1, #target2, #target3, #target4
{
width: 120px;
height: 120px;
background-color: white;
margin-top: 30px;
border-radius: 5px;
border: 2px solid black;
}


</style>
<script src="modernizr-latest.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

function allowDrop(ev){
   ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev){
   ev.dataTransfer.setData("content", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev){
   ev.preventDefault();
   var image = ev.dataTransfer.getData("content");
   ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(image));

  if($('#target1').find('#answer1').length == 1)
  {
    alert("CORRECT!");
  } else {
    alert("Wrong!");
  }
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="answerBoxes">
<div id="target1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
</div>
<div id="target2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
</div>
<div id="target3" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
</div>
<div id="target4" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
</div>
</div> <!-- end of answerBoxes -->
<div id="whatsWhatContent">
<div id="answers">
   <div id="answer1Box" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
       <img id="answer1" src="fall1.png"  draggable="true"    ondragstart="drag(event)" alt="Flower answer box draggable"/>
   </div>


   <div id="answer2Box" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
       <img id="answer2" src="files.png"  draggable="true" 
ondragstart="drag(event)" alt="Stem answer box draggable">
</div>

   <div id="answer3Box" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
      <img id="answer3" src="HOME.png"  draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" alt="Root answer box draggable">
</div>

   <div id="answer4Box" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
      <img id="answer4" src="web.png"  draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" alt="Leaf answer box draggable">
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thankyou very much, i had tried what you have changed and it didn't work for awhile, until I noticed you had linked the JQuery library. Is it possible for me to reset position of the answer boxes if alert is wrong?

Comment: @MattMeadows Anything's possible! ;-)

Comment: Ok thankyou, and sorry to ask so many questions, how might I go about adding if statements for the other answer boxes, at current if I just add another if statement in the same format as the first one, it alerts its wrong even if its right, and also alerts after the first one has been dragged and dropped.

Comment: I haven't tried to work through the mechanics of the game: I've just got the alerts working as per your original question. The remaining logic looks fairly simple, so have a crack at it, and ask a new question if you get stuck.

Answer (score 3):

Your code looks for `#target` in `#answer`, when you want it around the other way.

Try this:

```
if($('#target1').find('#answer1').length == 1)
{
  alert("CORRECT!");
}
```

Comment: I have tried both ways around to only no such luck.

Am I correct to put this if statement under the `function drop(ev)` in my javascript (see updated post) so that the if statement occurs upon drop

Comment: This definitely `alerts` if the answer is in the `<div>` (see [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RPP7e/)). I'd be looking at the drag-and-drop code. Since you're using jQuery anyway, why use `onDrop` rather than `$("...").on('drop', ... )`?

Comment: I've got modernizer linked up to my pages

Comment: By any chance because the image is within its own div that it could be causing issues?

Comment: It shouldn't affect the jQuery here - .find() will search the whole subtree. Otherwise, I don't know. It's only the image that's draggable, so I doubt it, but...

Comment: And i'm correct in thinking having 3 other images (different id's) wouldn't affect anything?

Comment: Have just moved the image into the div itself in code and no alert is output :(

Comment: @MattMeadows Other images with different IDs shouldn't affect anything. As to the DnD code, I'd have to set that up and try it, which I don't have time for right now. I'll take another look in a few hours if nobody else has cracked it.