# Div increases in size after item is dropped inside

Tags: javascript, html, css, drag-and-drop

I am creating a puzzle with pieces that can be dropped into place. Both the div's (empty placeholders tto place images) and the image fragments are the same size. However, upon dropping the image into the div, the div suddenly becomes larger, adding about 5px to the height. Any suggestions as to what may be causing this? Thanks in advance.

JS:

```
function allowDrop(ev){
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev){
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text",ev.target.id);
}
function drop(ev){
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
```

PHP:

```
<div id="mMiddle">
  <table class="pixTable">
    <?php
    for($index = '1'; $index <= '16'; $index++){
        if($index == '1')
            echo "<tr class='picRow'>
                <td class='droppable pixCell' id='pixCell".$index."'
                ondrop='drop(event)' ondragover='allowDrop(event)'>
                </td>";
        else{
            if($index % '4' == '0')
                echo "<td class='droppable pixCell' id='pixCell".$index."'
                    ondrop='drop(event)' ondragover='allowDrop(event)'>
                    </td></tr>";
            else if($index % '4' == '1')
                echo "<tr class='picRow'>
                    <td class='droppable pixCell' id='pixCell".$index."'
                    ondrop='drop(event)' ondragover='allowDrop(event)'>
                    </td>";
            else
                echo "<td class='droppable pixCell' id='pixCell".$index."'
                    ondrop='drop(event)' ondragover='allowDrop(event)'>
                    </td>";
        }
    } 
    ?>
  </table>
</div>
<div id="mRight">
    <div class="pixTable droppable" ondrop='drop(event)' ondragover='allowDrop(event)'>
        <?php
        for($index = '1'; $index <= '16'; $index++){
            if($index % '4' == '0')
                echo "<img class='draggable' id='mj".$index."' 
                    src='images/task3/mj".$index.".PNG'
                    draggable='true' ondragstart='drag(event)'><br>";
            else
                echo "<img class='draggable' id='mj".$index."' 
                    src='images/task3/mj".$index.".PNG'
                    draggable='true' ondragstart='drag(event)'>";
        } 
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.pixCell{
width: 99px;
height: 81px;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
border: 2px solid black;
background: white;
```

}

```
.pixTable{
    width: 396px;
    height: 326px;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    border-spacing: 0px;
    background: white;
    float: left;
}

.pixImg, .draggable{
    width: 99px;
    height: 81px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without an example of the bug is very hard to say where is the problem, but maybe it is caused by the images because they actually didn't 'float' the container.

Try adding **float: left** css property to them and see if that will help.

Comment: thanks. Related to this post, would you know how to prevent dropping an img into a cell that already contains an img?

Comment: This question may help you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17201570/check-if-a-div-contains-an-image-html5-drag-and-drop?rq=1